# How to pass image path using argparse in Ipythonnoteook

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, yolo

**I was trying to run object detection using YOLO but i am getting this error:**
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--image IMAGE] [--video VIDEO]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-f8a187e3-81d1-436a-8001-567712b2c2b0.json.
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
*Can any one tell me how can i give image path in argparse. I am running the code in Google Cloab.*

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Object Detection using YOLO in OPENCV')
parser.add_argument('--image', help='Path to image file.')
parser.add_argument('--video', help='Path to video file.')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can remove these arguments and replace with actual path to image/video where it is used. Or you can edit the code and add a default value

```
parser.add_argument('--example', default=1)
```